# How to find the originating userid of an rdp session?

Tags: windows, security, rdp

We have some shared privileged accounts that IS Security now wants to be able to track back to the person who used them.  Is that logged somewhere, or is there a way (preferably using Powershell) to find it (or to force a custom event log via login scripts)?  Example: user "Joe" is logged on to his laptop and then opens an rdp session to server "Tuxedo" using the "superuser" account.  How do I track/find/log the correlation between "Joe" and "superuser"?

Comment: Don't used shared accounts....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short version is that you can't. The only thing the RDP protocol cares about is who you are connecting to the remote server as.  There's nothing on the server or in the protocol that can tell you who initiated the connection other than the client's IP address.

If you already have access to the client system, the best you can do is correlate the client IP to the client system and check the client system's logs to see who was logged in at the same time the RDP session was initiated.

The better solution is to stop using shared accounts. But if there's some technical reason you need to keep them, you should gate access to the password in some sort of enterprise password vault that audits who checks out the current password and ideally auto-rotates it after it's checked back in.

Answer (score 0):

Everyone should be using their own unique "superuser" account, not a generic or all purpose "superuser" account.